# How to improve scannability in a nested table?

Tags: tables, visual-design

I have a list of events inside a table. the table's rows have zebra stripes that distinguish them from one another. the problem is that the text looks like a big unscannable block, it looks something like this:
[image]

since each cell has different type of content, I was looking for a way to tell them apart, one idea was more zebra stripes which looks overwhelming, like a table inside a table:
[image]

or only on mouse hover on the cell, but that could be confusing since it resembles a button or clickable area:
[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you need more columns, I'll draft that up into an answer later on when I have more time, unless someone beats me to it

Comment: Actually, since I just reread and see you mention they blocks will have different types of content, the extra columns idea won't work. I have some other thoughts, though, which I will share soon in an answer

Comment: A table is clearly not the design pattern to use here. Think out of the box... or use one ;-)

Comment: Can you share some real world format so that I can think about re-designing the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions from me:

> - Use the Zebra strips for each row, and they should appear the same in each section.
> - Remove the steps # column - use the same as divider between the Zebra Strips.
> - Align the content appropriately with readable line-height along with proper left alignment with gutters.

Here's a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## When tables are good

Tables are the go to solution when you have

- A list of things (rows)
- That should be easily sortable
- That share like attributes (columns) that are

  - Relatively short
  - Of unknown importance
  - Might be configured by the users
  - Which users will be doing deep analysis on

In other words, a bunch of stuff that would work well in a spreadsheet.

## Tables aren't the only answer

The data you show here (assuming it's a representative example) is a poor fit for tabular presentation. The "use a grid for everything" approach was a bad habit common in enterprise software up until very recently. The effort required to undo this mistake is daunting for many product teams, but your example is a good case study in why it must happen.

## Understand your users' needs

Ask yourself what the users are trying to accomplish when they come to this view. What are they trying to do or understand? There's a lot of information represented there and I can't even venture a guess based on what I see.

## Visually explain the data

Find the hierarchy of data that matters to your users and *design* a solution to communicate that. Right now, the most important thing is the "Step #" — after that it's all just noise.

Generally speaking, tables allow very little room to create visual hierarchies. When you have a pretty good idea of what the data is and what pieces of it are most important, there are two good, common solutions:

- Designed lists
- Cards

Here are a couple of examples:

**This designed list** has highly structured data that is important for scanning and freeform data that is important for further investigation. It's table-like, but without the unnecessary constraints.

[image: Timeline-style log list]

**The now ubiquitous card UI** gives structure to even more disparate data sets. This is helpful when you need to give structure to a set of items that share an important theme but differ greatly in specifics or contain a lot of busy sub elements. The card unifies the parent item and gives is space from it's equally complex neighbors.

[image: Google Now card UI]

Answer (score 0):

Apply more of a consistent hierarchy for your content inside of a cell. Look at the example below.

**Be consistent in your font size and color.**

Check out this article.

> One of the most important techniques for effectively communicating (or
>   “honoring”) content is the use of typographic hierarchy. Typographic
>   hierarchy is a system for organizing type that establishes an order of
>   importance within the data, allowing the reader to easily find what
>   they are looking for and navigate the content.

Source: [Understanding Typographic Hierarchy](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-typographic-hierarchy--webdesign-11636)

The left is how it is now. To the right are my suggestions. What is the most important information of your cell? Make sure it stands out. I'd make a difference between actual data (black, large), data labels (blue, small) and instructive text (grey, small).

[image]

I think the zebra idea is good to have. Keep them like the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that zebra striping is basically just an emphasized border, how about just adding borders to the cell level?
[image]